# Download manager to replace GetRight?

Tags: windows, download-manager

I've been happily using GetRight for the last 10 years or so, and today I found out (the bad way) that it won't work in Windows 2008 64-bit.

What is a good modern alternative that'll pretty much do the same thing?
I'm looking for:

- Being able to pause/resume
- Being able to specify many download streams at the same time (with/without mirrors)
- Being able to just give it a URL to download (I'd prefer if it doesn't interfere with browser's native handling of downloads)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Server 2008?

Comment: Yes, Windows Server

Comment: That's quite sad about GetRight, went to check their site / forums and the product looks abandoned. I used to use GetRight but switched to DownThemAll a while back.

Comment: I am just switching off DTA, as it gave me a Server 2008 download that was not pausible, and later not resumable after it 'gave up'.

Answer (score 11):

[DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201) is integrated into Firefox and has served me well. By default, it does not intercept Firefox downloads, but you can change this setting.

Answer (score 4):

[FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/en/download.htm)

Answer (score 4):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/), integrates with all browsers in system, monitors your clipboard for urls to download, works good with [FlashGet firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/220)

Answer (score 2):

I love [ReGet](http://www.reget.com/en/) [DeLuxe](http://deluxe.reget.com/).
For me it's killer features are:

- It can be tweaked a lot
- It finds mirrors automatically (though you can manually add them as well)
- It can generate a list of downloads easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [HiDownload](http://www.hidownload.com) and pretty satisfied with it. Lots of advanced features and gets the job done.

[image: HiDownload]

Answer (score 0):

[SoMud](http://www.somud.com/): a cross-platform multi-language download and share application with P2P support.

Answer (score 0):

[JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) is the best for me and meets all of your requirements plus :

> JDownloader is open source, platform independent, and written
>   completely in Java. It simplifies downloading files from
>   One-Click-Hosters like Rapidshare.com or Megaupload.com - not only for
>   users with a premium account but also for users who don't pay. It
>   offers downloading in multiple parallel streams, captcha recognition,
>   automated file extraction, and much more. Of course, JDownloader is
>   absolutely free of charge. Additionally, many "link encryption" sites
>   are supported - so you just paste the "encrypted" links and JD does
>   the rest. JDownloader can import CCF, RSDF and the new DLC files.