# download files from a windows machine

Tags: windows-xp, download, download-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download manager to replace GetRight?](https://superuser.com/questions/11874/download-manager-to-replace-getright)

Hi there, I am completely clueless when it comes to Windows sorry. If I am running Windows XP, what is a good program for download http/ftp files?

I constantly download large files via IE and if the connection is dropped I need to start the download again. If the connection drops I would like to restart the download from where it was up to. Free software suggestions please :)

thanks

Comment: Not an exact duplicate in the question itself, but the answers on this question are good for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [FlashGet](http://www.flashget.com/index_en.htm)

Free, can support FTP browser, can resume and support multiple download threads and has FTP browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can choose a software like Download Manager, It's free and it also make you able to manage multiple downlaod and provide download acceleration capabilities.

Another way you can follow, is to choose a different browser. Firefox, Chrome adn Safari natively provide download management capabilities.

Comment: When mark an answer as not useful, it's a good practice to leave a comment.