# How can I download a single file in multiple segments?

Tags: windows-7, linux, firefox, google-chrome, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download manager to replace GetRight?](https://superuser.com/questions/11874/download-manager-to-replace-getright)

Can I somehow download a single file in multiple segments simultaneously? Is there a browser plugin for Chrome/Firefox? Maybe a `wget` command?

Comment: Are you looking for a download accelerator?  A tool that splits a large file into multiple ones and then downloads the multiples independently?