# Is there software that can increase my transfer rate when downloading?

Tags: windows-7, download-manager

My current download manager does not appear to work, what alternatives exist for Windows 7?

Comment: Oh **please** stop screaming!

Comment: Super User is NOT the place for all caps rant about software.

Comment: Take a look at: [Download manager to replace GetRight?](http://superuser.com/questions/11874/download-manager-to-replace-getright), [Free Download Manager](http://superuser.com/questions/13536/free-download-manager). Saying that you're getting lower download speed as advertised is a bit vague and not a real question.

Comment: @Tom Hm... I'm not entirely sure that's what they meant. Could be just a bad ISP or bad remote server?

Comment: @slhck: There is nothing we can do when a product doesn't meet it's expectations, the OP should have at least tried more than one download manager before concluding that the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are misunderstanding how the program works.

Download managers “increase” the speeds of downloading files by making more than one connection to the server and having each one download  a different piece of the file, then combining them on your system.

Some servers limit the speed of each connection and some don’t. This means that for servers that limit the connection speed, that speed is multiplied by the number of connections, but for servers that don’t limit, the speed is your ISP’s limit.

Further, not all servers support *resume* (downloading a file from somewhere other than the its beginning), so with those files, download managers cannot help at all.

You are using a connection with a limit of 256Kbps which is fairly low, so your connection is easily getting maxed out. Also, the file(s) you are downloading may be on servers that do not support resuming and so the download manager is not effective.